# Firebase app integration error

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to integrate my app with Firebase, upon syncing the Gradle after updating, I'm getting this error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. >
>   Missing api_key/current_key object

Comment: have you added google-services.json file?

Comment: Show us your *gradle files*, thanks

Comment: Yes, I did and it was missing the api_key. Deleted and downloaded the google-services.json again. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

For some wired reason, the google-services.json downloaded from the firebase was missing api_key. Deleted the file, downloaded again the google-services.json from my app setting in the firebase console. Everything is fine then.